# Google Maps on Dojox mobile view

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dojo

The same question has been asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642788/how-do-i-add-a-google-map-to-a-dojox-mobile-view), but the accepted answer doesn't help (me, at least).

I use dojox.mobile.View to display two views that look like [this](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileOpenLayers/demos.html). Everything works fine, except the map container doesn't get displayed correctly. It is shown as a small box on the top page. Do I miss something on the layout file? Thank you!

```
<div id="view1" dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" selected="true">
    <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading">View 1</h1>
    <ul dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem" icon="images/icon1.png" moveTo="view2" transition="slide">Go To View 2
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="view2" dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" style="height:100%">
    <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="View 1" moveTo="view1">View 2</h1>
    <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.RoundRect" id="map_canvas" style="width:100% !important;height:100% !important;"></div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

```
<body style="visibility: visible;">
<div id="view1" class="mblView" selected="true" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" dojotype="dojox.mobile.View" widgetid="view1">
<div id="view2" class="mblView" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px;" dojotype="dojox.mobile.View" widgetid="view2">
    <h1 id="dojox_mobile_Heading_1" class="mblHeading mblHeadingCenterTitle" moveto="view1" back="View 1" dojotype="dojox.mobile.Heading" style="" widgetid="dojox_mobile_Heading_1">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mblRoundRect" style="width: 100% ! important; height: 100% ! important; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;" dojotype="dojox.mobile.RoundRect" widgetid="map_canvas">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
```

[Firebug logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Enal.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mobile view your using for the map view only has height:100% set where as the example has width + height 100%.

This can cause issues inside the div used for the map as its not picking up a width correctly. (i've seen a similar issue like this before, could be something else though)

EDIT:

Nothing pops out to me. Have you tried maybe using script to modify it ? something like:

```
var div = dojo.byId("map_canvas");
div.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
div.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
```

Comment: You mean adding style="width: 100%; height:100%" to the mobile view? Still the same problem.

Comment: yes thats what i meant, can you post the actual source from the browser to see whats being output?

Comment: by bad. didn't test it out i had given you the wrong script, tested this (edited the code above) and it worked

Comment: On my PC, the map is only shown in the top left corner, while the rest is grey area. Strangely, when I press F12 to debug, the whole map is loaded. Is it displayed correctly on your PC?

Comment: yes, I was playing around with the code a bit, I added width / weight to all the divs to make sure it was getting picked up but it shouldn't be necessary given the javascript. I'm using a different dev environment however so it will be a little different to yours, perhaps try adding in position left / top through javascript also. Shouldn't need it but could fix it. it sounds odd that it works after a refresh. have you put in console print outs to see is the code running (console.log("Height: " + div.style.height) )

Comment: Yes, it does run. The other app (with different layout container) runs succesfully. But when the same code I put in this app, it doesn't work. No idea.

Comment: I stripped it away to just the one mobile view so I could see it running. I would do this until you can find the issue but it sounds like you maybe your not using the same css? or using some that has been designed for a different layout perhaps?

Comment: Having your code commented, one app runs well (I have cleared the cache). Woa, really pulling my hair off. Been spending the whole day on this topic only. Anyway, your code works. So, thanks!

Comment: ha no problem, glad I helped. ya this stuff can be tricky sometimes, dealing with multiple browsers is also probably going to be fun ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar display problem with Dojo mobile + Google maps api version 3.

Simons solution did not work, but there was another way.

I don't create new topic, just give you this simple hint: Always check if Google maps loads AFTER DOM (for example using `require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){ ... })`