# Improper google map display

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating a view with a google map in it when a certain click from a li element event is triggered.
For the first time the map is shown ok. And the result is this:

[image]
*http://postimg.org/image/eolnn0411/*

but when I click in another li element to create a new map it is shown like this:

[image]
*http://postimg.org/image/576um203l/*

I've noticed a strange behavior that if I resize the browser window the map turns to display ok after that.

I'm using the following code:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

var map;
map = new google.maps.Map(node, myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
        });
```

Edit:
Related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642788/how-do-i-add-a-google-map-to-a-dojox-mobile-view), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598680/google-maps-on-dojox-mobile-view).

Edit 2: By using the workaround of using setInterval() works sometimes. SO it seems that the problem is the map not being ready for the event.

Comment: You should provide complete code, the best is to put it into jsfiddle live example!

Comment: I'm using the dojo toolkit and having some troubles getting it to work on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger Google maps(v3) resize event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evRG5/3/) will help you to find the difference.

Comment: I'm facing problems resizing the map without using jquery

Comment: I've added that line of code but can't get it to work. Or I'm not understanding how the resize event works.

Comment: @mluis I've not tried Dojo, may this [post](http://lgrammel.blogspot.in/2009/05/google-map-in-dojo-floatingpane.html) help you.

Comment: I'm using google maps v3, on that post it is used google maps v2. I don't believe that's dojo making this to not work. I've talked about dojo above in the context of the creation of a similar jsfiddle example.

Comment: It happens that that line of code is running before the map is set. Tried to use a delay with setInterval and do the resize in that callback and it worked.

Comment: Is there any way to call 'google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');' synchronously after the map is set on the dom?